# Here I solve Word Ladder-2 Leetcode-126 Question In python

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

```
import queue
from string import ascii_lowercase
from collections import deque

def findSequences( startWord, targetWord, wordList):
        
        set1={}
        for i in range(len(wordList)):
            set1[wordList[i]]=1
        
        q=queue.Queue()
        q.put(startWord)
        
        usedlevel=[]
        usedlevel.append(startWord)
        level=0
        
        ans=[]
        vec=[]
        
        while q.empty() is False:
            vec1=q.get()
            vec.append(vec1)
            q.get()
            
            if len(vec)>level:
                level+=1
                
                for it in usedlevel:
                    del set1[it]
                     #set1.remove(it)
            n=len(vec)        
            word=vec[n-1]
            
            
            if word==targetWord:
                if len(ans)==0:
                    ans.append(vec)
                    
                elif len(ans[0])==len(vec):
                    ans.append(vec)
                    
                    
            for i in range(len(word)):
                original=word[i]
                
                for j in ascii_lowercase:
                    word[i]=j
                    
                    if word in set1:
                        vec.append(word)
                        
                        q.put(vec)
                        usedlevel.append(word)
                        vec.pop()
                word[i]=original
        return ans
```

Above code does not give any output.
What is reason behind that?
where I  make mistake in above code

Can anyone why above code give wrong answer for Leetcode 126 .
Where i did make mistake .
I dont know why i did not get any answer. Can anyone Tell me what wrong in my code .

Comment: When Stack Overflow indicates that more information is needed, it is not the intention that you just repeat a few times the same thing. Instead provide information on what you have done to debug the situation. Which debugger did you use, where did you put breakpoints, which variables have you inspected, ...Etc.

Comment: [tag:dsa] stands for Digital Signature Algorithm. This question has nothing to do with it. Please don't add irrelevant tags!

Answer (score 0):

> Above code does not give any output. What is reason behind that?

Your code is executing a second `q.get()` when there are no items. By default `get` will wait for the queue to provide an item, but since you have no multithreaded code that would do that, it will wait for ever.

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get) of `Queue.get`:

> If optional args block is true and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until an item is available.

This "block" is exactly what is happening in your case.

> Can anyone Tell me what wrong in my code .

There's too much wrong in your code.

- `del set[it]` tries to delete `startWord`, but that word is not in the `wordList`, so this throws an exception.
- `word[i]=j` and `word[i]=original` will raise an exception: strings are immutable. You cannot assign a character to some character position in a string. You need to make a new string.
- `q.put(vec)` puts a **list** on the queue. That is not right, as your code expects to pull strings from the queue, not lists.
- Doing `vec.append(word)` followed by `vec.pop()` a few statements later is useless. I have no idea what you want to do there.
- The `vec` list is not kept in sync with the queue. The item that is pulled from the queue will in general have a "history" that is quite different from what is in `vec`. By consequence `vec` will collect words right after each other that have more than one letter difference, and so this algorithm can easily produce wrong results. The information about the *path* should not be kept in a separate `vec` list, but should be maintained *attached* to the queued items, as each item in the queue has its own path that lead to it.
- This algorithm is not efficient enough, as it must try each of the 26 letters for each position which for words with 5 letters means that 26<sup>5</sup> (over 11 million!) words have to be created, just to find all possible jumps from one word to the next.

Concluding: there are many problems with this approach, and even if you correct most of them, the last point will still be problematic: the algorithm has bad efficiency. You need a different approach.